# Automatic line break when inserting user macro

Tags: confluence

I'm using [confluence from atlassian](https://www.atlassian.com/software/confluence) and I need a way to modify the text size, family, and color by using a user macro.  I defined my macro as follows:

```
## @param 0:title=forecolor|type=string|desc=Text foreground color.  Enter colors such as: red / blue / green / etc.
## @param 1:title=backcolor|type=string|desc=Text background color.  Enter colors such as: red / blue / green / etc.
## @param 2:title=size|type=string|desc=Enter size in px, for example, 20px.
## @param 3:title=family|type=string|desc=Enter the font family (listing can be found here: http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/fonts.en.html) (example: serif).
<span style="color: $param0; background-color: $param1; font-size: $param2; font-family: $param3;">$body</span>
```

Now the user can choose this macro 'Stylish' as such:

[image]

However confluence automatically adds a new line

tag with content I want to appear next to it.  Assume I had the text:

> The brown fox jumped over the cow.

And I wanted to set the background color of the word `fox` as red and its forecolor to yellow.  If I apply this macro to that word I end up with something like this:

[image]

So it automatically puts a new line in on the word that has the macro assigned to it.  I want to keep it inline the entire sentence and apply the formatting to a single word.  Even If I select `inline` in the options it still puts it in a new line.

The result comes out to this:

[image]

Here is a screen shot in edit mode:

[image]

I have selected it inline, and published the page still the result shows `the brown` on one line `fox` on another line and finally `jumped over the cow` on yet another line.  **Atlassian Confluence 5.4.4**  This macro should work like the `<span>` tag so that the item doesn't appear as a block style element.

Comment: I can't see your examples

Comment: Which radio button do you have selected for the macro body processing?

Comment: When I selected 'inline' in the options I managed to get it to work. I had to hit backspace with the cursor in front of the word after the macro though. Play around in the editor some more until it works, I can promise you it's possible.

Comment: This does not work, I have clicked inline and I have hit backspace in front of the word.

Comment: Are you publishing or previewing the page to see what it actually looks like, or are you just looking at the page in edit mode? I took your exact macro code and it's working flawlessly for me.

Comment: Ive published the page..I can add images to what it does, maybe you can share the images?

Comment: What browser are you using?  Im on chrome.

Comment: Tried IE same issue....

Comment: Also what version of confluence have you tried this on?  We are on Atlassian Confluence 5.4.4,

Comment: I've tried it on IE 9 and the most recent releases of chrome and firefox. We're running 4.3.7 but I can test it on 5.4 on my dev server. EDIT: Naturally the dev server is down.

Comment: Well I tried to bounty this question but that too expired with no answers.  I also had posted this on the atlassian q&a forum but got 0 hits.  I went ahead and created a support ticket with atlassian and will provide any updates if they can resolve this.

Comment: I just fiddled with this on version 5.5 and couldn't get it to work like it did in 4. Hopefully atlassian will come back with a response/fix for your support ticket

Comment: @MNRSullivan - Awesome that you were able to reproduce it on the same version we are running.  Strange how it worked in version 4 but not the latest version - this happens to us all the time, we add new functionality which ends up breaking prior functionality that used to work :).  Well I appreciate you verifying this.  We did get an e-mail from atlassian but the unfortunate thing is this is in their backlog :(.

Answer (score 0):

There is no good way of doing this. There's a JIRA issue you can track: [CONF-15860](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/CONF-15860).

Comment: Please add this as a comment not an answer, I've also opened a jira issue for this (see the comments section).